# Upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, cannot log in

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, login, fglrx

I recently did the automatic upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, but I can't log in to my Ubuntu boot anymore.

I get a dark blue/black screen after the Ubuntu loading screen. If I move the mouse, I can see it, but no screen loads. I am able to ctrl-alt-f1 and get a login screen, and from there can do 'sudo service light-dm start'. This will get me a login screen, but when I go to log in, it will take me back to the login screen over and over.

I reinstalled fglrx several times, as well as ubuntu-desktop. The logs all look fine. I also regenerated xorg.conf.

The only thing I see wrong is that fglxrinfo returns `Error: unable to open display (null)` instead of what it's supposed to return.

Any idea what is causing this error, and how to fix my GUI?

Edit: I noticed that sometimes when go over to ctrl-alt-f1, it's hung up on either mysql or it just finished loading "networking." I'll check the network log next.

Comment: Did you actually upgrade all the way to 14.10, or do you mean 14.04?

Comment: What tool or command did you use to do the upgrade?

Comment: @eliahkagan yea, sorry. I'll fix it when I get to a computer.

Comment: @neon_overload a window popped up asking if I wanted to upgrade and I said yes.

Comment: @JFA this will help for sure : http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: @igaurav ok I changed the permissions of .Xauthority to $USER:$USER, and that didn't load, so reconfigured lightdm and set it to lightdm, and now it loads

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue and the problem was the permission with the file ~/.Xauthority 
so i took backup and deleted it and rebooted this solved my login issue

Comment: That didn't seem to work, and I can't even launch the login screen now with `start lightdm`

Comment: This is the solutions i used for my issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop